# Custom Adapter for ListView, Filtering Issue

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, filtering

I have this class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
```

and override this method

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new Filter()
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
        {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = originalData;
                results.count = originalData.size();
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<Map<String,String>> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

                results.values =  filterResultsData;
                results.count =  filterResultsData.size();
            }

            return results;
        }


        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
        {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>)filterResults.values;
            if (filterResults.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see in the above code, in the **performFiltering** method, in the **else** block, I've done nothing to populate the filterResultsData. Why? Because if I do any operation, it will results in app crashing when i try to filter the listview.

Means, all is well, I can run the apps in emulator, the listview appears, but as soon as I'm typing a word in the textbox (to filter), the app crash. (No error code or any other message at the console)

Please help. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's ; _No error code or any other message at the console_ ?

Comment: This message appears, but the build is successful: `Note: C:\***\app\MyAdapter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`

Comment: Ah, you are referring to build log, right? How about LogCat, is there any red text?

Comment: Ya, my bad.. i can see the error, and it relates to the note above.. i change from the log level Assert to Verbose, now i can see the error..  `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry` I need to update my question, adding the code involve..